# Cakephp 2: How to generate sql from records for every table in the database

Tags: mysql, insert, cakephp-2.0, dump

I need to find a way to generate an sql file (insert statements) for every table in the database. My database can store records for many sites and I need to export to sql only those records for a specific site. I'm using MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using sqlyog tool> If so there is an option there

Comment: I need to accomplish this from php, not an external tool. And every table has a column that say for what site that record is, and this column need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, [This link](http://faq.1and1.com/web_space__access/mysql/13.html) will help you to create mysql script using php.